# android: generate random number without repetition

Tags: java, android

can anybody help me in making a method to generate random number without repetition in Android?
The maximum number is: `prjcts.size();` it's my JSON Array. And the return value should be in integer.

What I've already had is:
`int i = (int)(prjcts.size() * Math.random());` I casted the method 3 times, because I need 3 random generated numbers. It works, but I don't know how to make it without repetition. So those 3 numbers won't be the same between each other.

Thank you

Comment: Without repetition in a loop or in one runtime or what?

Comment: I did this int i = (int)(prjcts.size() * Math.random()); 3 times with a different variable. Because I need 3 random generated number with the maximum is the max number of my JSON entry. it works, but I don't know how to make it without repetition. So those 3 numbers won't be the same between each other. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried just using [Math.random()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)?

Just do some casting magic and you'll be good to go:

```
int index = (int)((double)prjcts.size() * Math.random());
```

**Edit:**

If you want prevent repetition, you could create a list with all the possible indices.

```
int max = prjcts.size();
List<int> indices = new ArrayList<int>(max);
for(int c = 0; c < max; ++c)
{
    indices.add(c);
}
```

Then each time you want a random index, just pick a random item from the list, removing it after from the list when you're done

```
int arrIndex = (int)((double)indices.size() * Math.random());
int randomIndex = indices.get(arrIndex);
indices.remove(arrIndex);
```

`randomIndex` is now guaranteed to be a never-before used index of of your JSON list.

Comment: Yes I've done this already before: int i = (int)(prjcts.size() * Math.random());  it works, but I don't know how to make it without repetition. So those 3 numbers won't be the same between each other. Thx

Comment: Thank you! this is my favorite solution! :)

Comment: No problem, but to be honest, I wasn't aware of `Collections.shuffle()`. Haphazard's solution is a more succinct way of doing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 10):

I mentioned in your other question how to do this..

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int jsonMax = prjcts.size();
for(int i = 1; i<=jsonMax; i++)
    list.add(i);

Collections.shuffle(list);

for(int i=0; i<jsonMax; i++) {
    int n = list.get(i);
    //n is a random, unique number between 1 and prjcts.size()
}
```

Comment: The generator is never referenced, why is it needed?

Comment: I just removed it - good catch.  Also, thanks for the correction Itay.

Comment: Minor optimization: preset the size of your ArrayList to prjcts.size() to avoid multiple allocations.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get N random numbers with out repeat from 0 to N-1 would be to create an array of those N numbers and create a random number that will pick one index of that array. Then remove the index from that array, and continue on with the N-1 numbers and so on.

```
class NoRepeatRandom
{
  private int[] number = null;
  private int N = -1;
  private int size = 0;
  public NoRepeatRandom(int minVal, int maxVal)
  {
    N = (maxVal - minVal) + 1;
    number = new int[N];
    int n = minVal;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      number[i] = n++;
    size = N;
  }

  public void Reset() { size = N; }

  // Returns -1 if none left
  public int GetRandom()
  {
    if(size <= 0) return -1;
    int index = size * Math.random();
    int randNum = number[index];

    // Swap current value with current last, so we don't actually
    // have to remove anything, and our list still contains everything
    // if we want to reset
    number[index] = number[size-1];
    number[--size] = randNum;

    return randNum;
  }
}

void Test()
{
  NoRepeatRandom nrr = new NoRepeatRandom(0, 10);
  for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    System.out.println("Random number: " + nrr.GetRandom());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, you could try using the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) algorithm, which has a Java implementation of it [here](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/). The Mersenne Twister is a random number generator which has a period of 2^19937 − 1, so you're pretty much guaranteed to not get the same random number.