# Fill an array with random numbers android/ java

Tags: java, android, arrays, random, int

I'm having trouble doing the following and have no idea how to do it: I would like to fill an array generated with random numbers (1-40) and also make it so that the number doesn't repeat. Also, is there a way to make the array go to the next value on its own using. So let say I have test [1] = "3" and then test [2] = "6". Is there anyway to make it go to the next value instead of calling test [2]?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your last 3 sentences make ***no*** sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android: generate random number without repetition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807512/android-generate-random-number-without-repetition)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < 40;)
{
    int rand = ((int)(Math.random() * 40)) + 1;
    if(!list.contains(rand))
    {
        list.add(rand);
        i++;
    }
}
```

or:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) list.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(list);
```